# How to split a string on character change?

Tags: string, python-3.x, split

**Problem**

Let's say I have the string `aaaabccdddefgg`, I want to split the string on character change, using Python 3.

So it would output

```
['aaaa', 'b', 'cc', 'ddd', 'e', 'f', 'gg']
```

for the given example.

**Question**

Is there a tool for doing this? Or should I be writing my own implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for that.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = 'aaaabccdddefgg'
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s)]
['aaaa', 'b', 'cc', 'ddd', 'e', 'f', 'gg']
```

Comment: Groups, of course! Should have known to search for that, since SQL has similar wording. Thanks!